# initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] error in C

Tags: c

I've faced the following error in my code.
please guide me, what my problem is?

```
void myfree(void *buf)
{
void *start = (long)ptr & PAGE_MASK;
size_t offset = (long)ptr & ~PAGE_MASK;
/* Will segfault here on double-free */
size_t len = *(size_t *)start;
```

error:

```
    initialization makes pointer from integer without a  cast                 
   void *start = (long)ptr & PAGE_MASK;
               ^
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: `(long)ptr` is a `long`. `(long)ptr & PAGE_MASK` is a `long`. You are trying to initialize a `void*` with this `long`. You can cast it. This is exactly what the error says.

Comment: Ummm..  (long)......

Comment: The error message says it all: The code tries to initialise a pointer from an integer, which is not nice.

Comment: That looks like a warning, not an error. I don't know how they could have made the warning message any more clear... You're assigning an integer (`long`) to a pointer-type variable (`void*`), and the compiler doesn't like the fact that you're not using an explicit cast to convert from `long` to a pointer type.

Comment: You are getting down voted because the question feels incomplete.  One pet peeve of mine is that people down vote with no explanation.  (I think this makes it hard to improve questions)

Comment: Only use a cast iff 1) It is really necessary 2) You understand **all** implications and 3) **fully** accept them.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you are trying to (looks like) put a `long` into a `void *` without a cast.

It's hard to advise you further without knowing a bit more about how those other variables are typed.

Something like this should be closer to what you are looking for.

```
void * start = (void*) ((long) ptr & PAGE_MASK);
```

Comment: If available on the OP's implementation use `uintptr_t` instead of `long` to (in a portable manner) make sure casting does not drop any bits from the pointer value.